# Why is_heap() not validating the heap created by me though it is valid conceptually

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, heap

I wrote a heap implementation in C++ and later today I came to know that, there are inbuilt functions in C++11 that can make any range based container a heap.

So out of curiosity I made a vector into heap using my own implementation and used the function `make_heap()` and then ran `is_heap()` on both of them.

The one made using `make_heap()` verified to `true`, but mine did not, even though it is technically valid.

Source code and screenshots below

**Header Files**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
```

**Main heapify function**

```
vector<int> heapify(vector<int> nums, string const & type) {
    int n = nums.size();
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int parent = floor((i-1)/2);

        if (parent >= 0) {
            if (type == "min") {
                if (nums[i] < nums[parent]) {
                    swap(nums[i], nums[parent]);
                }
            } else {
                if (nums[i] > nums[parent]) {
                    swap(nums[i], nums[parent]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nums;
}
```

**Function that builds the heap**

```
vector<int> buildHeap(vector<int> const & nums, string const & type) {
    vector<int> heap;
    int n = nums.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        heap.push_back(nums[i]);
        if (!heap.empty()) {
            heap = heapify(heap, type);
        }
    }
    return heap;
}
```

**Remove the top most element**

```
int getTop(vector<int> & nums, string const & type) {
    int n = nums.size();
    if (n < 0) {
        throw string("Size of array is less than 0");
    } else {
        int minElem = nums[0];
        swap(nums[0], nums[n-1]);
        nums.pop_back();
        nums = heapify(nums, type);
        return minElem;
    }
}
```

**Main function**

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> nums = {45, 56, 78, 89, 21, 38, 6, 67, 112, 45, 3, 1};
    vector<int> heap = buildHeap(nums, "min");
    for (int num : heap) {
        cout << num << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    cout << std::is_heap(nums.begin(), nums.end(), greater<int>()) << "\n";
    make_heap(nums.begin(), nums.end(), greater<int>());
    for (int num : nums) {
        cout << num << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    cout << std::is_heap(nums.begin(), nums.end(), greater<int>()) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Screenshots of output on console and verification on https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Heap.html

[image: Output Console]

[image: Output verification]

Comment: your predicate is reversed

Comment: Where? Can you point out the source code or logic where I am wrong.

Comment: pls refactor your posted code so I can cut/paste it straight into my IDE. then i will update it to show you where

Comment: Paste the code in the exact sequence and it will work just fine. For running purposes please use `using namespace std` and `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and things will work just fine.

Comment: include<bits/stdc++.h> does not exist in Visual Studio.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` -- Don't do this.  Include the appropriate headers, not that thing.

Comment: Run it on GCC as a single file. It will work fine.

Comment: Source code - https://pastebin.com/g3VBrx1z

Comment: I will definitly not install gcc to test yout code.

Comment: http://ideone.com/ You can run the file here as well.

Comment: @deadpoolAlready -- The persons helping you may not have GCC.  Again, include the correct headers.  There is a duplicate question on why that "bits/stdc++.h" should not be used.  What's wrong with learning what the actual headers are?

Comment: Included the appropriate header files as well.

Comment: don't use string in that way, pass a comparator

Comment: @Sopel I don't exactly know how to pass and use a comparator. I can write one, but I don't know how to pass an inbuilt comparator for the functions I build.

Comment: there are nice examples of std::less, std::greater on cppreference

Comment: @Sopel will you be able to link me to those documents?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not run the first is_heap on your heap, you run it on the original vector. That one is obviously not a heap.

This line is not checking your heap:

```
cout << std::is_heap(nums.begin(), nums.end(), greater<int>()) << "\n";
```

Your heap variable is called `heap`:

```
cout << std::is_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), greater<int>()) << "\n";
```

Comment: I want to check using `is_heap()` that if the heap that I have actually developed using my code is valid or not.

Comment: Yes, understood it now. I made a horrible mistake :D

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation makes the heap as a *copy* of the original sequence. So you need to validate the copy (`heap`), not the original sequence (`nums`).

```
    cout << std::is_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), greater<int>()) << "\n";
```

Your sequence *is* a heap, [here's proof](http://rextester.com/DHGA71255):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec = {1, 6, 3, 67, 45, 21, 38, 89, 112, 56, 45, 78};
    std::cout << is_heap(vec.begin(), vec.end(), greater<int>());
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: I missed it. I checked it on heap and now it works just fine :/ Sorry my bad. Thanks for pointing it out.